# Django - CSRF Failed: CSRF cookie not set

Tags: python, django

I want to create a API that has login / logout / signup / edit etc, but when I try it in Postman i get the error: CSRF Failed: CSRF cookie not set

I've noticed that if the user is not logged in, The API works fine but after the login I get the CSRF error when using any url from it ( /logout/, /login/ etc)

```
views.py
`@csrf_exempt
 @api_view(['POST'])
 def login_user(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return JsonResponse({"detail": "User is logged in!"})
    
    body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
    body = json.loads(body_unicode)
    
    nickname = body['nickname']
    password = body['password']

    user = authenticate(nickname=nickname, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        
        logout(request)
        return JsonResponse({"response": "Login success!"})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({"error": "Nickname or Password are incorrect!"})`

settings.py
`MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]`


log out functionality 
@api_view(['POST'])
def logout_user(request):
    logout(request)
    
    return JsonResponse({"response": "User logged out!"})
```

I've seen that I should get a CSRF token in the cookies section in Postman, but the only thing i get is a sessionId

Comment: add  the log out fonctinality